# Manga where the main character is kicked out of a guild for being stuck at Lv1, but his sword awakens new abilities after his departure

Tags: story-identification, manga

The beginning of the title shows a kid fighting a massive dragon and cutting it down to size with one swing of his sword. Even veteran knights fending off the onslaught for their kingdom are impressed by his strength, being known far and wide around the world.

Flashing back to the past, he is informed by his Guild Master that he is to be expunged from their sect and made to leave, effective immediately, on the grounds of not having moved past his level 1 cap in years.

After traveling a bit and fighting off a vicious, tiny slime monster, despite its initially innocuous appearance, he gains some new skills despite his level barely even going up; if at all. Over time, his sword gains the ability to shapeshift, morphing into a number of different armament or equipment forms, like a rifle, a motorbike, a cat-eared human female. As well as giving him otherworldly knowledge about the modern day Earth era, in order to better streamline his blade's transformation abilities and newfound sentience.

Eventually, word travels about the poor kid's unjust removal and a top-ranked female adventurer was less than thrilled to hear this news. While the guild leader jerk who fired the hero of the story is alone in his room, sipping some chutney or whatever cheap liquor whilst reminiscing about some shadowed figure pushing him to exile the lead character for a sizable reward, said adventuress came bursting into the room, startling the half-balding older man, demanding to know why he threw him out, despite the fact he was still in the midst of awakening his true abilities.

After some flimsy excuses from the owner about both that and his sexual harassment of some of his female clerks, she outright clocks the perverse geezer, knocking him, along with a couple of his teeth, clean the hell out and sending him flying into a wall, before quitting his stupid guild in order to find what can only be assumed was her protégé.

The manga is black and white but hasn't been serializing long, so far as I know. if you know the name of it, please give me a name and reply back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Even Though I'm the Only [Divine Sword User] in the World, I Was Called Out of Combat Strength, and I Became the Strongest With an Awakened [Divine Sword]](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/2u1wtvs/sekai-de-yuiitsu-no-shinken-zukai-na-no-ni-senryokugai-to-yobareta-ore-kakusei-shita-shinken-to-saikyou-ni-naru)***...?

> Albert...
> Commonly known as Al, is a adventurer in murphin.
> He is also the only one in the world who is a [divine sword user], a job that no one else has.
> But this job is too weak.
> It is neither particularly strong nor useful.
> Although he had a divine sword, its attack power was only 1!
>
> The guild master forcefully expelled him from the guild.
>
> Al is at a loss, but he can't get a job because of the rumors that are spreading in the town.
>
> He has no choice but to go hunting for monsters, and defeats the first one.
>
> From there, the cheat-like performance of the [divine sword] begins to blossom.

The main character is Albert Geisel, known as the Divine Swordsman.

At the start of the first chapter, we see him on a battlefield, having apparently just defeated 100,000 enemies singlehandedly. A bunch of enemy monster reinforcements -- including a large, fire-breathing dragon -- show up, and he defeats them with ease. Albert is accompanied by an army, including a Hero and a Great Sorcerer, but he doesn't seem to need their help and they mostly just stand and watch what he's doing in awe.

The story then jumps back in time a year, and we see Albert in the office of his guild master, Simon. Simon states that he let Albert join his adventurers' guild because he heard that his job as a Divine Swordsman would awaken sooner or later, but it still hasn't done so and Albert has spent the past year doing nothing but general chores, so Simon fires him and tells him to get out.

Albert subsequently encounters a slime while wandering through the countryside on the outskirts of town. He's never fought a monster before, but decides to kill it in order to earn some money. Upon doing so, he sees that his attack power has increased to level 3, so he kill another 29 slimes, increasing his attack power further. As he continues to level up in subsequent chapters, his sword unlocks new 'modes' enabling it to morph into other things, such as a rifle, a motorbike, and a young woman with cat ears.

> [image: "Even Though I'm the Only [Divine Sword User] in the World, I Was Called Out of Combat Strength, and I Became the Strongest With an Awakened [Divine Sword]," chapter 3, page 17.]

In chapter 2, we learn that Simon drove Albert out of the guild under orders from a man named Golgo.

In chapter 5, a female adventurer named Emilia storms into Simon's office -- angry about Albert's dismissal and Simon's sexual harassment of female members of his staff -- and punches him in the face, knocking one of his teeth out and sending him flying into a wall.

> [image: "Even Though I'm the Only [Divine Sword User] in the World, I Was Called Out of Combat Strength, and I Became the Strongest With an Awakened [Divine Sword]," chapter 6, page 2.]